# Check Overlapping intervals integerfield validation django python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

can anyone help me how to solve overlapping validation in django

moldel.py

```
 start = IntegerRangeField()
 end = IntegerRangeField()
```

form.py

`class CheckForm(forms.ModelForm): def clean(self):`

```
start=cleaned_data.get("start")
    end = cleaned_data.get("end")
    conflicts = Check.objects.filter(
        start_bbch__lte=end,
        end_end__gte=start,
    )
    if any(conflicts):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("overlapping not allowed" % conflicts.count()))
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to check for overlapping you need to make sure that neither the start nor the end of your new object is within an existing interval.

So I would suggest something like this:

```py
conflicts = Check.objects.filter(
    start_bbch__gte=start, end_end__lte=start
) | Check.objects.filter(
    start_bbch__gte=end, end_end__lte=end
)
```

Comment: @Kane If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. Thank you!

Comment: can you please check  check this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324921/when-there-is-no-overlapping-i-am-getting-overlapping-validation-error)